# How I should implement creating quiz in Flask Quiz app?

Tags: python, flask, backend

I'm creating a quiz web app in Flask. Among others, the page will include user managment system, solving quizes and creating your own quizes for other users. I'm planning to put quizess in a SQLAlchemy database. I want to create route where users can create a quiz. They will pass a title, questions and for every question, for possible answers with information, which one is correct. My problem is that, I'm not sure how I could do it. For example I'm not sure how I should handle the problem of number of quiz questions, so how many field for questions should be generated.
I was thinking about asking user how many questions the quiz will have or creating other route for every question, but they this sollutions were not making much sense when I was thinking about implementing them.
So my question is, what will be the best way to implement creating quizess in this type of app?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should start with database design. then use Flask-login/Flask-user to create login for members. Then you should use Flask-admin, for the admin panel. and about the last question how many questions should there be in a quiz. make it static eg. 5 but the question bank should have more questions hence you can randomize the questions.